# Bash command to change size of bash window

Tags: bash

Is there any command to change size of bash window  ( for example to set size on 150x90) ?
I dont want to change .profile file.

Answer (score 39):

Some (but not many) terminals accept the ANSI escape sequence

```
\033[8;h;wt
```

(where `\033` is the ASCII control character `ESC`, and `h` and `w` are height and width in decimal).

For example, in XTerm (*after* allowing window ops through the Ctrl-RMB menu or the `allowWindowOps` X resource),

```
$ printf '\033[8;40;100t'
```

will resize the window to 100x40 characters.

Comment: I added '\033[s' (to save the cursor position) at the start and '\033[u' (to restore the cursor position) at the end. Otherwise, the next line was printed over the prompt, in my case.

Answer (score 13):

```
$ resize -s 90 150
```

see the file manual for more options.

```
$ man resize
```

Comment: Also doesn't exists on RHEL 7, please tell what RPM they are part

Answer (score 6):

The resize command works to change the size of the window, but you may experience some strange things if you don't also tell the terminal to use the whole area. This is what I use, and it works well.

```
#!/bin/bash
resize -s 33 100
stty rows 33
stty cols 100
```

Comment: if it helps anyone.. to get current size `stty size`
its handy to print it out using `stty size | cut -d ' ' -f 1` (height) and `stty size | cut -d ' ' -f 2` (width)

Answer (score 4):

I usually only want to change the console width, so combining answers/comments from [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243640/446106) and [Jimmy MG Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309866/446106), I came up with this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

cols="$1"
rows="$(stty size | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

printf '\033[8;%d;%dt' $rows $cols
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a question for https://superuser.com/, anyways, how do you launch your terminal window? Most of the terminal emulators have command line args to specify the size.

Another option, if you need to change it after the window appeared `wmctrl` might help you.

Comment: The problem exist only if I connect via serial line.